# XSD validation for enum values

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

is it possible to restrict the occurance of the element value a specified number of times?
e.g:

```
<sample>
   <values>
       <value>SAMPLE1</value>
       <value>SAMPLE1</value>
   </values>
</sample>
```

In possible values for  are "SAMPLE1", "SAMPLE2", "SAMPLE3".  can occur max three times but each value must be unique.

In the example "SAMPLE1" occurs twice which is incorrect. Is it possible to restrict this in XSD?

Comment: [xsd sequence](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp) should help here.

Comment: @khachik, the issue is about restricting the possibles values of the element. In the question, how can we restrict the "SAMPLE1" occurs only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `<value>` to be unique in particular scope (e.g. in `<values>`). Here's example:

```
<xs:element name="sample" type="SampleType">
    <xs:unique name="valueKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="*/values"/>
        <xs:field xpath="value"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Using `selector` element you define the scope and using `field` you define which element should be unique in the scope.

For more information see [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_unique.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the value to occur "a specified number of times" provided that number is 0 or 1: use xs:unique as described by Oleg. If you want a different number, you'll need xs:assert which comes in XSD 1.1.